# PHP for .NET

Tags: .net, php

I know there are implementations of Python and of Perl for .NET. Have you ever heard of any similar plans for PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recall there's something called [Phalanger](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=Phalanger) which runs PHP on .NET

Comment: Note it isn't in active development anymore. Maybe it will be.

Comment: December 2009: "... our team are again actively working on Phalanger. The new release is coming soon..."

Answer (score -2):

no, there's not and I don't think there will be as it doesn't really make much sense. Python makes more sense as it's a dynamic language and there's no current equivalent in .net. I believe you can use Phalanger which compiles PHP to CIL but it's not a first class .net language.

Comment: It is an implementation of the PHP language for the CLI. Why should it be a first class language?

Comment: So, why Perl eventually makes sense?

Comment: it does make sense... especially when porting applications from PHP -> .NET.  There are many other areas including performance gains, etc...